# Creating an unreferenced array in Java?

Tags: java

Say I have a method such as:

```
public void printElements(int[] array)
```

How could I send an int[] as an argument without declaring it previously (so, actually create it inside the message). I want to avoid something like:

```
int[] anArray = { 5, 3, 10 };
Foo.printElements(anArray);
```

And use something (although this doesn't work) like this instead:

```
Foo.printElements( new int{ 5, 3, 10 } );
```

Comment: new int[]{ 5, 3, 10 }

Comment: Depending on how you want to use this function, it may be worth considering a `...` argument. `public void printElements(int... nums)` can be called with `Foo.printElements(anArray)` or `Foo.printElements(1, 2, 3)`.

Comment: You should also take a look at vararg methods, since they seem to be exactly what you want.

Comment: @user2357112 it is not if you want to sent other parameters as well after the array.

Comment: I tried researching and I found nothing about it. Anyway thanks guys, I feel pretty silly now :D